# jQuery Error after JSPX Parsing in Spring Application

Tags: jquery, spring, jsp

I have a really strange problem:
I'm using the Spring Framework 3.0.5 in my Application. For rendering the views I use the Tiles Framework.

This is the source of the layout jspx file:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:jsp="http://java.sun.com/JSP/Page" xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" xmlns:tiles="http://tiles.apache.org/tags-tiles" xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/tags" xmlns:util="urn:jsptagdir:/WEB-INF/tags/util" >  
<jsp:output doctype-root-element="html" doctype-public="-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" doctype-system="http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"/>          
<jsp:output omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

<head>

</head>

<body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/js/jquery.js"></script>
    <img id="testimg" src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/images/logo.png" onclick="$(this).fadeOut()" />
</body>
```

Now the problem: every time I load the page, I get a JavaScript error from the jQuery call and no further js code is executed:

```
    Error: c.removeAttribute is not a function
```

But if I copy the source of the page and paste it into a local file and open it with a browser, everything is fine (the difference is, the tomcat doesn't deliver the page).

The rendered page looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head />
<body>
    <script src="/myContext/resources/js/jquery.js"
    type="text/javascript">

    </script>
    <img onclick="$(this).fadeOut()"
    src="/myContext/resources/images/logo.png" id="testimg" />
</body>
</html>
```

The image is displayed correctly and the query.js is also loaded.
I'm really running out of ideas. I hope someone can help me!!

Thanks in advance!

Update:
This effect occurs only with Safari and FF. On Google Chrome it works!!
And I forget to mention, that I'm working an a Mac...

Answer (score 0):

You've mentioned that you are using JSPX. I suggest that you try to add a comment between `<script>` and `</script>`, which is

```
<script ...> <!-- please keep me --> </script>
```

Otherwise, JSPX compiler will make the `<script>` tag into `<script .../>`, which will be wrong when browser renders it. (This is what I guess, and I think it should be right.)

I don't know the detailed reasons, but I have met the same problem with you, and I fixed it using that method. If you could figure out detailed reasons, please let me know.

Thank you!